# .Formula brings error with punctuation marks vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with adding formula to a cell through VBA.
Everything is ok till the moment when I add punctuation mark like "(" to it.
What I'm doing wrong here?
I've tried already using chr() function and it doesn't work.

```
 Do Until ws.Cells(i, 1) = ""
 If ws.Cells(i, 7).Value <> "" Then
    If ws.Cells(i, 7).Value <> 0 Then
        ws.Cells(i, 7) = 200
        ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = 0
        ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = 0
        ws.Range("J" & i).Formula = "=IF(H" & i & "-F" & i & "<=0;0;H" & i & "-F" & i & ")"
```

Regards,
Ukalo

Comment: BigBen formula should be "=IF(H5-F5<=0;0;H5-F5)" of course with actual row number instead of 5

Comment: oh,sorrry. Run-time error 1004 / Application-defined or object defined error

Comment: Which line produces the error? Did you initialize and declare `ws` correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
ws.Range("J" & i).Formula = "=IF(H" & i & "-F" & i & "<=0;0;H" & i & "-F" & i & ")"
```

with:

```
ws.Range("J" & i).Formula = "=IF(H" & i & "-F" & i & "<=0,0,H" & i & "-F" & i & ")"
```

If you want to make it easy, see:

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formulalocal)

Comment: Yep, that's right. I wouldn't track that by myself. Thank you Gary's Student.  Do you know if it's connected to local set up of excel? And should I in other functions change is as well from ";" to " ' " ?

Comment: @Lukasz  Using `FornulaLocal` make it easier to copy formulas from the worksheet to VBA code.